# Rails Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error on a partial render through js. The partial only contains a table.

The partial is being called but the error message in the browser console is showing the first `<` of the table tag as the unexpected token.

```
<table class='table table-sm'> # <- this line errors
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Part #</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>SCS-#10-24X.375-BLK</td>
      <td>Countersunk screw, #10-24 X .375, Black oxide</td>
      <td>2.0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

_check_it.html.haml

```
- if @part.part_structures == 0
  No components
- else
  %table.table.table-sm
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Part #
        %th Description
        %th Qty
    %tbody
      - @part.part_structures.each do |ps|
        %tr
        %td= ps.component.partNo
        %td= ps.component.description
        %td= ps.qty
```

check_it.js.erb

```
$("#that_one").replace("<%= j render(partial: 'check_it') %>");
```

parts_controller.rb

```
def check_it
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render partial: 'check_it', :content_type => 'text/html', part: @part}
  end
end
```

Why would the partial error out in the JS console for the beginning of the table tag?

Comment: seems like your `{render.... }` block in parts_controller is the issue, what action is this?is it `check_it`?

Comment: yes. I updated the code there

Comment: since your `check_it.js.erb` already does the partial swapping, you don't need that `{render...}`  and it's incorrect anw because of `format.js` which mean rails is sending back a js response, not html.

Comment: Looks like the bad {render...} was completely blocking the js.erb from being called. I stripped the format.js {} and it's working. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if `check_it.js.erb` file in the same folder, no need to render from controller. It will automatically does as long as method name is same also.

```
# parts_controller.rb
def check_it
  #@part is already class instance variable. no need also
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}
  end
end

# parts/check_it.js.erb
console.log("<%= @part %>")
$("#that_one").replace("<%= j render(partial: 'check_it') %>");
```